# Search form conflicting with commenting forms jQuery script

Tags: jquery

I have a page with dynamically generated commenting forms and I'm using jQuery's `$("form").submit(function() {` to submit the forms.

It works just fine on the commenting system, but it has also grabbed the other forms on the page such as the search form that I want to perform its default action of sending the user to a search page with the results of the search.

How do I keep this script but change it so the search form isn't grabbed by the `$("form").submit` function?

Comment: Can you share some code so that people here can help you

Comment: At a wild guess, you should probably have a class on either the search form or the comment forms, so change your selector to `$("form:not(.searchformclass)")` or `$("form.commentform")` respectively. Also make sure, whenever you refer to the form inside the submit function, you refer to it as `$(this)`.

Comment: That $("form:not(.searchformclass)") worked perfectly. Cheers bro!!! Can you add more than one class in the not parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The selector you mention:

```
$("form")
```

will select *all* form elements on the page. What you need to do is use a more specific selector like an id or class. You mention you have multiple comment forms, so perhaps something like this:

```
<form class="commentform"></form>

<form class="commentform"></form>

<form id="searchform"></form>

<script>
$("form.commentform").submit(function() {
   // the same handler will apply to all commentform forms, but
   // the keyword 'this' will reference the particular form that
   // triggered the event
});

$("#searchform").submit(function() { });
</script>
```

(Where for the search form I've given an example of selecting by id.)

Further reading:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/05/jquery-selectors-examples.html
- http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-most-out-jquery-selectors

Comment: Hey nnnnnn for some reason the $("form.commentform") way didn't work but the $("form:not(.searchformclass)") did. I have no explanation why since both ways are correct. But $("form:not(.searchformclass)") did solve my problem. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Hi Mike. It should work either way provided you actually have those classes on you forms as shown in my answer. (Your question didn't show any html or class information, so I just made up an example.)